# How to factorize entire DataFrame in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a Pyspark DataFrame and I want to factorize the entire df instead of each column to avoid the case that 2 different values in 2 columns have the same factorized value. I could do it with pandas as following:

```
_, b = pd.factorize(df.values.T.reshape(-1, ))  
df = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Categorical(x, b).codes)
df = df.replace(-1, np.NaN)
```

Does anyone know how to do the same in Pyspark? Thank you very much.

Comment: AFAIK, pyspark/spark dataframes have no such thing. One option is that you could implement it yourself by taking the distinct values of a column and mapping it to an ordinal value, or do data validation using a validation library (such as great expectations, deequ, etc.) where you specify which values you expect in your dataframe.

Comment: @k88 got the idea, thank you very much :)